# MyPy: module not found mypy-extension

Tags: python, docker, mypy

I am working on python app using docker. I am using `mypy` as type checker, during checking I got an error for `Callable[NamedArgs]`.

version `mypy = "^1.2.0"`

Upon this, I used `from mypy_extensions import NamedArg` and corrected the error.

```
def bar(*, id: int) -> bool:
  return True

foo: Callable[[NamedArg(int, "id")], bool] = bar
```

This time type checking is **passed** and docker build process started, But during lanuch/up, I am getting error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypy_extensions'
```

After, this I ran `poetry add mypy-extensions --group dev`, it installed successfully.

version `mypy-extensions = "^1.0.0"`

Then I ran again, still **getting same error**.

Please help.

Comment: The issue looks like environment config (e.g. do you install dev dependencies in docker? If not, `--group dev` won't affect your build). Please open a shell in container and examine your environment contents, make sure you have `mypy_extensions` there. Also please note that `NamedArg` and other callable extensions are deprecated as superseded by structural subtyping (`Protocol`). Your `Callable[[NamedArg(int, "id")], bool]` should be `class MyCallable(Protocol): def __call__(self, id: int) -> bool: ...` instead.

Comment: Hi SUTerliakov, Thanks. I made the changes as you shown in the example using `Protocol`, It is working now.